# Generating Incremental sequence of number in dataframe using python for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a data frame (df) mentioned below:

```
ID
1
1
1
2
2
3
```

I want to generate the output as below using for loop in Python

```
ID Cnt
1    1
1   2
1   3
2   1
2   2
3   3
```

I have tried the below code:

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    df['cnt']=0
    if df.ID[i]==df.ID[i]+1:
        df['cnt']=df['cnt']+i
        break
        i+=1
```

Unfortunately its not providing the desired output

Comment: Can you provide the output it is giving (beyond simply that it is not the desired output)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's going on here, but I immediately notice that the `i+=1` line comes after the break but inside the if statement so it will never be executed.

Comment: @Oliver.R It's tagging cnt=0 for all records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]})

L = [] 
for unique_value in df['ID'].unique():
    L += list(range(1, sum(df['ID'] == unique_value) + 1))

df['cnt'] = L
```

Edit (Explanation) 
This code initialize L as empty list, and concatenate L and [1, 2, ..., frequency of the unique value] for every unique value in df['ID'].

Comment: Hi There, its working. Can you please explain the logic?

Comment: I edited the explanation. See the answer, and please accept this answer.